# How to download AWS Lambda Layer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI is it possible to download a Lambda Layer?

I have seen this documented command.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_GetLayerVersion.html

But when I try to run it with something like below.

```
aws lambda get-layer-version --layer-name arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:209497400698:layer:php-73 --version-number 7
```

I get this error.

> An error occurred (InvalidParameterValueException) when calling the
>   GetLayerVersion operation: Invalid Layer name:
>   arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:209497400698:layer:php-73

Is downloading a layer possible via the CLI?

As an extra note I am trying to download any of these layers
https://runtimes.bref.sh/

Comment: I just edited my answer to include an example for one of the arn's in that webpage. Can you let me know if that answers the question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It should be possible to download a layer programmatically using the AWS CLI. For example

```
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-layer-version.html
URL=$(aws lambda get-layer-version --layer-name YOUR_LAYER_NAME_HERE --version-number YOUR_LAYERS_VERSION --query Content.Location --output text)
curl $URL -o layer.zip
```

For the arn's in that web page, I had to use the other api which uses an arn value. For example:

```
# https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/get-layer-version-by-arn.html
URL=$(aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:209497400698:layer:php-73:7 --query Content.Location --output text)
curl $URL -o php.zip
```

HTH

-James

Comment: this works. if you wanna run directly on command line 

curl $(aws lambda get-layer-version-by-arn --arn arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:12333444:layer:ner-deps-layer:4 --query Content.Location --output text) -o l.zip

Comment: How do you load the layer to the AWS CLI ?

Comment: @hYk please make a new question

Comment: I was able to make it work using`--layer-cache-basedir` flag.

Comment: There is also the case where you use a layer from someone else, if he forgot to give download permission to the layer, you can use a script that takes anything under the /opt folder, zipps it and put's it into an S3 on your account, for later downlaod and modify.

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka can you please help to give in some references or commandline on how this done, i am in a similar situation

Comment: @Nataraj I am referring to the code you can write in your Lambda function. in your preferred language: 1. zip /opt/*   2. upload to an s3 you control the zip file (u do not have to zip it if it is small enough)